# CSRF on module forms for anon users

Tags: tokens

My module has 2 small forms which allow visitors to submit certain information.

Problem is when I am not logged in, no CSRF token is being added to the forms - so anonomous users/everyone are bypassing the CSRF. Can't find any documentation on this issue, could anyone point me in the right direction so i can get my CSRF tokens?

It is a requirement of my security testing that all forms include CSRF.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`drupal_prepare_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7) it says

> since tokens are session-bound and forms displayed to anonymous users are very likely cached, we cannot assign a token for them.

If you do want to go ahead with this, the following works when quickly tested with the default search and comment forms.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!isset($form['#token'])) {
    $form['#token'] = $form_id;
    $form['form_token'] = array(
      '#id' => drupal_html_id('edit-' . $form_id . '-form-token'), 
      '#type' => 'token', 
      '#default_value' => drupal_get_token($form['#token']),
    );
  }
}
```

Be careful about page caching however (and a reverse proxy if you use one) if you do go down this road.

Comment: Saw that, do you know of any work arounds?

Comment: I've not heard of any I'm afraid. Looking at the code I don't see a problem with just populating `$form['#token']` and `$form['form_token']` but this isn't tested. Would you be able to update your question to include why you're worried about CSRF on an anonymous account?

Comment: I have strict security testing requirements. The forms can't be left open to attack. It's a fairly simple thing to implement, i'm not sure why Drupal is making it so difficult.

Comment: I think the Drupal way is to use registered users as and when you're opening up functionality that you want to protect from CSRF. I've never needed to have a form that was protected from CSRF and visible to anonymous users (not to say it can't happen, just wondering if it isn't an unusual situation).